# Display pixels values as an image

Tags: python, image, numpy, image-processing, matplotlib

So I have a **1280** × **960** **.TIF** format image. I have extracted all pixels which is **1.200.000** pixels.

After that, I have done some calculations using each pixel on the image, let's say :

```
result = each_pixel * some calculation
```

The `result` list has also 1.200.000 values.

Now what I am trying to do is to display two different images, the first with the original pixel values which means the original image, the second one with the `result` list, which means the result calculated for each pixel displayed in the exact same x and y coordinates of the original image.

How can I do that? I suppose that we can do it with something like the colormap but I am not sure.

Comment: Rearrange `result` so that it is 1280*960 and use `plt.imshow` for both?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `matplotlib` way of doing this would be:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import numpy as np

plt.imsave('filename.png', np.array(result).reshape(1280,960), cmap=cm.gray)
plt.imshow(np.array(result).reshape(1280,960))
```

*Note*: You could also use [`glumpy`](http://glumpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Answer (score 3):

You could reshape the one-dimensional array `result` in-place by changing its [`shape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.shape.html) property:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage import io

image = io.imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/5KUry.png')

each_pixel = image.ravel()
some_calculation = 64

result = each_pixel // some_calculation
result.shape = image.shape

fig, (ax0, ax1) = plt.subplots(1, 2)
ax0.imshow(image, cmap='gray')
ax0.axis('off')
ax0.set_title('image')
ax1.imshow(result, cmap='gray')
ax1.axis('off')
ax1.set_title('result')
plt.show()
```

[image: lions]