# Errow displaying image from array of pixels in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, image-processing

I have a (numpy) array of pixels acquired as:

```
''' import numpy and matplotlib '''
image = Image.open('trollface.png', 'r')
width, height = image.size
pixel_values = list(image.getdata())


pixel_values = np.array(pixel_values).reshape((width, height, 3)) # 3 channels RGB
#height, width = len(pixel_values), len(pixel_values[0])
```

I need to compute digital negative of this image -

```
for y in range(0,height):
   for x in range(0,width):
       R,G,B = pixel_values[x,y]
       pixel_values[x,y] =(255 - R, 255 - G, 255 - B)
```

tried displaying image from above pixels with the help of [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44755458/display-pixels-values-as-an-image)

```
plt.imshow(np.array(pixel_values).reshape(width,height,3))
plt.show()
```

But it just displays a blank (white) window, with [this error](https://pasteboard.co/H1XfFHq.png) in CLI:

Comment: The error message seems pretty self explanatory. The size of your reshaped array must be the same size as the original. What are the values of `width` and `height`?

Comment: let's say it is an image 210 by 210 px

Comment: I am really sorry for the typo, I actually tried to map the image into same width and height, but couldn't.

Comment: You are probably going to have to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

The aim here is to achieve a negative transformation of an image.

Pixel translations can be directly applied to the R, G, B band using `Image.point` method.

```
image = Image.open('trollface.png')

source = image.split()
r, g, b, a = 0, 1, 2, 3

negate = lambda i: 255 - i

transform = [source[band].point(negate) for band in (r, g, b)]
if len(source) == 4:  # should have 4 bands for images with alpha channel
    transform.append(source[a])  # add alpha channel

out = Image.merge(im.mode, transform)
out.save('negativetrollface.png')
```

**EDIT** using OP's procedure, you have:

```
im = Image.open('trollface.png')

w, h = im.size

arr = np.array(im)
original_shape = arr.shape


arr_to_dim = arr.reshape((w, h, 4))

# Note that this is expensive.
# Always take advantage of array manipulation implemented in the C bindings
for x in range(0, w):
    for y in range(0, h):
        r, g, b, a = arr_to_dim[x, y]
        arr_to_dim[x, y] = np.array([255 - r, 255 - g, 255 - b, a])


dim_to_arr = arr_to_dim.reshape(original_shape)

im = Image.fromarray(dim_to_arr)
out.save('negativetrollface.png')
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I would appreciate it if you could help identify my mistake.

Comment: You need to reshape an _ndim 2_ array to _ndim 3_. What you're looking for is `.reshape((width, height, 4))`

Comment: tried setting 4 instead of 3 shows new error :
plt.imshow(np.array(pixel_values).reshape((width,height,4)))
ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged

Comment: Please see edit. I was able to run this successfully.

Comment: this works [when I reshaped to w,h,3 instead of 4(no alpha)]! 
what do you mean implementing c bindings in this context?

Comment: If you're working on a `png` there should be an alpha channel but I may be missing something. On the issue of C/Fortran bindings, using one of numpy's array API that implements array transformation in C or Fortan binary is generally more memory efficient and performant than array manipulation using nested loops in Python